# Mclust freezes with small dataset

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, freeze, mclust

I am trying to use the Mclust() function from the R-package mclust on a dataset with 500 observations and 2 variables, and I want to identify 2 clusters.

```
> head(data)
           x          y
1  0.9929185 -1.9662945
2  8.2259360 -0.7240049
3  3.3866952 -1.8054764
4 -0.5161490 -2.3096992
5  1.8931073 -1.8928091
6  4.0833228 -1.9045669

> Mclust(data, G = 2)
fitting ...
  |===============================================================                                          |  67%
```

This should produce an output relatively quickly, but freezes at 67%.
I ran this function multiple times over different datasets, and had no problems whatsoever. It even works if I only include observations up to row 498, but fails as soon as row 499+ is included.

```
498 -1.710175250 -1.612248596
499 -5.666497204  5.565422240
500 -3.649579976  1.552779499
```

I have uploaded the whole dataset in my GitHub repository: https://github.com/fstermann/bthesis/tree/main/MclustFreeze

I would greatly appreciate if anyone has an idea why this is happing with this specific dataset.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mclust_5.4.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.5 tools_4.0.5
```

Comment: I can replicate the problem on R 4.0.5 on Mac (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0) but at smaller data sizes (about 400 on R.app and 300 on RStudio (1.4.1103). You should probably contact the package maintainer: `maintainer("mclust")`.

Comment: I did, seems to be a problem with the VVE model...

*Fitting mclust model VVE with G = 2 seems to be the problem. The EM algorithm eventually will converge but it may take a very long time. If you try the same VVE model with G = 3 it has no problem.
We are aware of this problem but we haven't been able so far to identify the reason for that.*